# Alter Object Type Definition in Oracle to add more columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, type-conversion

I am using a custom type with around 36 different data columns as an array in my **PL/SQL** procedure which allows me return data in the form of **array**, which i modify at my front end as required. As per the requirement, i need to modify the custom type which now requires modification of the existing columns data that i send , i.e, i need to add 2 more column data to the same. Is it possible to modify the existing data type using `ALTER` or do i need to use `Replace` only for the same?
I am using Oracle 10g and am looking for a way to use `ALTER` only

The existing definition of my custom data type is :

```
create or replace
Type TYPE_RD_CONTRACT_PRODUCT_PRICE as Object
(
       CONTRACT_PRODUCT_TERM_ID NUMBER,
       SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID         NUMBER,
       SHIP_FROM_ORG_NUMBER     VARCHAR2(64),
       SHIP_FROM_ORG_NAME       VARCHAR2(128),
       SHIP_TO_ORG_ID           NUMBER,
       SHIP_TO_ORG_NUMBER       VARCHAR2(64),
       SHIP_TO_ORG_NAME         VARCHAR2(128),
       PRICE_START_DATE         DATE,
       PRICE_END_DATE           DATE,
       FOB_PRICE                NUMBER(18,4),
       DELIVERED_PRICE          NUMBER(18,4),
       MISC_FEE                 NUMBER(18,4),
       PRICE_BASIS_ID           NUMBER,
       PRICE_BASIS              VARCHAR2(32),
       MISC_FEE_BASIS_ID        NUMBER,
       MISC_FEE_BASIS           VARCHAR2(32),
       FREIGHT_START_DATE       DATE,
       FREIGHT_END_DATE         DATE,
         FREIGHT_FUEL_DESC_ID     NUMBER,
       TARGET_FREIGHT_BRACKET   NUMBER(18,4),
       FUEL_SURCHARGE_TYPE_NAME VARCHAR2(64),
       TRUCKLOAD_QTY            NUMBER(18,4),
       MILEAGE                  NUMBER(18,4),
       FREIGHT_BRACKET_BASIS    VARCHAR2(32),
       TOTAL_BASE_FREIGHT       NUMBER(18,4),
       MISC_FEE_1               NUMBER(18,4),
       MISC_FEE_2               NUMBER(18,4),
       MISC_FEE_3               NUMBER(18,4),
       MISC_FEE_4               NUMBER(18,4),
       MISC_FEE_5               NUMBER(18,4),
       FREIGHT_MANAGEMENT_TYPE_ID NUMBER,
         FREIGHT_MANAGEMENT_TYPE_NAME VARCHAR2(64),
         REDI_DCT_ORG_ID          NUMBER,
       REDI_DCT_ORG_NUMBER      VARCHAR2(64),
       REDI_DCT_ORG_NAME        VARCHAR2(128),
       IS_REDI_DCT             NUMBER,
       FREIGHT_COST_BASIS_ID   NUMBER
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/alter_type.htm#LNPLS99995), you can use `alter type` to add attributes:

`alter type TYPE_RD_CONTRACT_PRODUCT_PRICE add attribute (new_val integer);`

Comment: can multiple attributes be added in the same statement?